# strange output from Python 3 ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I'm parsing a really simple `.xml` file with this snippet

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse('/home/user/dummy.xml')
print(tree.getroot())
```

the output is

```
<Element 'doc' at 0x1d2f090>
```

which is correct, but I was expecting something cleaner and as simple as

```
doc
```

is this the normal output ? How I can clean this ?

I'm using Python 3.x

---

the `dummy.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <branch name="testing" hash="1cdf045c">
        text,source
    </branch>
    <branch name="release01" hash="f200013e">
        <sub-branch name="subrelease01">
            xml,sgml
        </sub-branch>
    </branch>
    <branch name="invalid">
    </branch>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the default output for an `Element`. If you want just the tag, try:

```
print(tree.getroot().tag)
```